# Counterexample of a sequence in $l^2(N)$ which is pointwise convergent but not 2-norm convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Here $l^2(N)$ is the set of real sequences $x_{n}:N\rightarrow R$ with $\sum{|x_{n}|^2}<+\infty$. I need a sequence in this space that convergences pointwise but not in the norm $\|x_{n}\|=(\sum {|x_{n}^{2}|})^{1/2}$ .

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try constructing a sequence each of whose coordinates converge to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_n:=(0,,,,0,1,0,0,...)$, where the $1$ is on the nth- place.

Answer (score 1):

$(1, \frac 1  {2^{1/2}} ,\frac 1  {3^{1/2}},...,\frac 1  {n^{1/2}},0,0...)$, $n=1,2,...$ will do.